# Render HTML with wp_send_json

Tags: html, json

I'm trying to render HTML with wp_send_json, but it doesn't work, HTML is not formatting :

It's look like "`<i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i> 1 200`" Any idea how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Um, `wp_send_json()` is for sending _JSON_, hence the name, not HTML. Why are you trying to use it to render HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Instad of using `wp_send_json()`, just echo the HTML and end with a `die;` or `exit;`. This should return plain HTML (content) to your script.